# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, generics

During deployment in glassfish got the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor

StackTrace:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/generic/GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:772)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:739)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:520)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:412)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:400)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:474)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:52)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:100)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:69)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1212)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/generic/GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.determineUrlsForHandler(DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:79)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>       ... 50 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
>       at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
>       at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>       ... 61 more

POM.xml(WEB):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cptu.egp</groupId>
        <artifactId>eGPService</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>standard</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
        <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>itext</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>htmlToPDF</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlToPDF</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>json_simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json_simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-webmvc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>spring-webmvc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-context</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.snowdrop</groupId>
        <artifactId>snowdrop-vfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javacsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
        <version>javacsv</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfreechart</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jcommon</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibmjceprovider</groupId>
        <artifactId>ibmjceprovider</artifactId>
        <version>ibmjceprovider</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ibmpkcs</groupId>
        <artifactId>ibmpkcs</artifactId>
        <version>ibmpkcs</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ipgclient2</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipgclient2</artifactId>
        <version>ipgclient2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>KeyGenApp</groupId>
        <artifactId>KeyGenApp</artifactId>
        <version>KeyGenApp</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>local_policy</groupId>
        <artifactId>local_policy</artifactId>
        <version>local_policy</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sunjce_provider</groupId>
        <artifactId>sunjce_provider</artifactId>
        <version>sunjce_provider</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>us_export_policy</groupId>
        <artifactId>us_export_policy</artifactId>
        <version>us_export_policy</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

POM.xml(DAO)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cptu.egp</groupId>
        <artifactId>eGPModel</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1B</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: code ? configuration ?

Comment: Please, add your `pom.xml` or a list of libraries. And a full stack trace too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. I got the solution today. I used a lower version of spring-web-mvc than other spring jars.After updating that one it works fine